# Can I verify if I'm logged into AZuread without genearting a login cycle?

Tags: azure-active-directory

I'd like to be able to check if I'm I'm logged into Azure AD without generating a login cycle.

Is there anyway to do this?

I looked at the cookies that show up going to login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant} but none stand out, and even if I could figure it out I'd expect MSFT could change these anytime.

The user name isn't required - just to see if an app or browser is authenticated.

Answer (score 0):

Figured this one out.

To do this you issue an authorized with a "prompt=none"

If the account is logged in, it will return a code.  If the account is not
logged in, it returns an error.